# Unity quiz game, problem to make three attempts for each question

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Unity Engine C#
My game contains a timer, points, a panel where pictures and videos are shown and a separate panel where the text pops up, when the answer is incorrect the red color pops up and it moves to the next question, I need each question to have 3 attempts, the first attempt to throw out only the text, if the answer is wrong, you get the next chance, the text of the question is the same, only now the picture pops up in the picture panel, and if the answer is incorrect again, then it's the last chance, again text and picture or video, if you make a mistake that time too, you get 0 points and it continues, I put that one answer brings 50 points, so the second attempt would carry 30 and the third 15, if the answer is not correct then 0.. I tried to explain as briefly as possible so that it is not long, I hope you understand me, I tried in every way and I can't succeed, I hope you can help me, my code has Serbian words,i have 4 scripts.I apologize for the long message, but I really need help to do this, I also sent you pictures at the end of the message.

FIRST ONE
MesanjeListe/shuffling the list

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class MesanjeListe
{
    public static List<E> MesanjeSadrzajaListe<E>(List<E> ulaznaLista)
    {
        List<E> originalLista = new List<E>();
        originalLista.AddRange(ulaznaLista);
        List<E> nasumicnaLista = new List<E>();

        System.Random r = new System.Random();
        int randomIndex = 0;
        while (originalLista.Count > 0)
        {
            randomIndex = r.Next(0, originalLista.Count);
            nasumicnaLista.Add(originalLista[randomIndex]);
            originalLista.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        }

        return nasumicnaLista;
    }
}
```

SECOND SCRIPT
Quiz data script/Skripta Podataka Kviza

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Sadrzaj Pitanja", menuName = "Sadrzaj Pitanja")]

public class SkriptaPodatakaKviza : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Pitanje> pitanja;

    
}
```

THIRD SCRIPT
QuizUI/KvizUI

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class KvizUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private DrugiKvizMenadzer drugiKvizMenadzer;
    [SerializeField] private Text pitanjeSaTekstom, Bodovi, Vreme;
    [SerializeField] private List<Image> slikeZivota;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject krajIgre, meniIgre, glavniMeni;
    [SerializeField] private Image pitanjeSaSlikom;
    [SerializeField] private UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer pitanjeSaVideom;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource pitanjeSaZvukom;
    [SerializeField] List<Button> opcije, UIDugmad;
    [SerializeField] private Color bojaZaTacno, bojaZaNetacno, obicnaBoja, bojaZivota;

    private Pitanje pitanje;
    private int trenutniPokusaj;
    private bool odgovoreno;
    private float duzinaZvuka;

    public Text BodoviTekst { get { return Bodovi; } }
    public Text VremeTekst { get { return Vreme; } }
    public GameObject KrajIgre { get { return krajIgre; } }



    void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < opcije.Count; i++)
        {
            Button lokalnoDugme = opcije[i];
            lokalnoDugme.onClick.AddListener(() => NaKlik(lokalnoDugme));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < UIDugmad.Count; i++)
        {
            Button lokalnoDugme = UIDugmad[i];
            lokalnoDugme.onClick.AddListener(() => NaKlik(lokalnoDugme));

        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void PostaviPitanje(Pitanje pitanje)
    {
        trenutniPokusaj = 0;
        this.pitanje = pitanje;
        SlikaVideoZvuk();

        switch (trenutniPokusaj)

        {
            case 1:
                pitanjeSaSlikom.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                pitanjeSaTekstom.text = pitanje.informacijaPitanja;
                break;
            case 2:
                pitanjeSaSlikom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                pitanjeSaSlikom.sprite = pitanje.pitanjeSaSlikom;
                pitanjeSaTekstom.text = pitanje.informacijaPitanja;
                break;
            case 3:
                SlikaVideoZvuk();
                pitanjeSaSlikom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                pitanjeSaSlikom.sprite = pitanje.pitanjeSaSlikom;
                pitanjeSaTekstom.text = pitanje.informacijaPitanja;
                pitanjeSaZvukom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                duzinaZvuka = pitanje.pitanjeSaZvukom.length;
                pitanjeSaZvukom.Play();
                break;
        }

        switch (pitanje.tipPitanja)
        {
            case TipPitanja.TEKST:

                pitanjeSaSlikom.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                break;
            case TipPitanja.SLIKA:
                SlikaVideoZvuk();
                pitanjeSaSlikom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                pitanjeSaSlikom.sprite = pitanje.pitanjeSaSlikom;
                break;
            case TipPitanja.VIDEO:
                SlikaVideoZvuk();
                pitanjeSaVideom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                pitanjeSaVideom.clip = pitanje.pitanjeSaVideom;
                pitanjeSaVideom.Play();
                break;
            case TipPitanja.ZVUK:
                SlikaVideoZvuk();
                pitanjeSaZvukom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                duzinaZvuka = pitanje.pitanjeSaZvukom.length;

                StopCoroutine(PustiZvuk());

                break;
        }

        pitanjeSaTekstom.text = pitanje.informacijaPitanja;
        List<string> listaOdgovora = MesanjeListe.MesanjeSadrzajaListe<string>(pitanje.opcije);
        for (int i = 0; i < opcije.Count; i++)
        {
            opcije[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = listaOdgovora[i];
            opcije[i].name = listaOdgovora[i];
            opcije[i].image.color = obicnaBoja;
        }
        odgovoreno = false;
    }

    IEnumerator PustiZvuk()
    {
        if (pitanje.tipPitanja == TipPitanja.ZVUK)
        {
            pitanjeSaZvukom.PlayOneShot(pitanje.pitanjeSaZvukom);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(duzinaZvuka + 1f);

            StartCoroutine(PustiZvuk());
        }
        else
        {
            StopCoroutine(PustiZvuk());
            yield return null;
        }

    }

    void SlikaVideoZvuk()
    {
        pitanjeSaSlikom.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        pitanjeSaSlikom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        pitanjeSaZvukom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        pitanjeSaVideom.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void NaKlik(Button dugme)
    {
        if (drugiKvizMenadzer.StatusIgre == StatusIgre.IgraSe)
        {
            if (!odgovoreno)
            {
                odgovoreno = true;
                bool vrednost = drugiKvizMenadzer.Odgovor(dugme.name);

                if (vrednost)
                {
                    dugme.image.color = bojaZaTacno;
                }
                else
                {
                    dugme.image.color = bojaZaNetacno;
                }
            }
        }
        switch (dugme.name)
        {
            case "Kreni":
                drugiKvizMenadzer.PokreniIgru(0);
                meniIgre.SetActive(false);
                glavniMeni.SetActive(true);
                break;

        }

    }
    public void PonoviDugme()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }




    public void OduzmiZivot(int index)
    {
        slikeZivota[index].color = bojaZivota;
    }
}
```

FOURTH SCRIPT
SecondQuizManager/DrugiKvizMenadzer

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class DrugiKvizMenadzer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private KvizUI kvizUI;
    [SerializeField] private List<SkriptaPodatakaKviza>sadrzajPitanja;
    [SerializeField] private float ogranicenjeVremena = 30f;
    private List<Pitanje> pitanja;
    private Pitanje izabranoPitanje;
    private int brojacBodova = 0;
    private float trenutnoVreme;
    private int ostatakZivota = 3;
    private StatusIgre statusIgre = StatusIgre.Sledece;
    

    public StatusIgre StatusIgre { get { return statusIgre; } }

    public void PokreniIgru(int index)
    {
        brojacBodova = 0;
        trenutnoVreme = ogranicenjeVremena;
        ostatakZivota = 3;
        pitanja = new List<Pitanje>();




        for (int i = 0; i < sadrzajPitanja[index].pitanja.Count; i++)
        {
            pitanja.Add(sadrzajPitanja[index].pitanja[i]);

        }

        IzaberiPitanje();
        statusIgre = StatusIgre.IgraSe;
    }


    void IzaberiPitanje()
    {
        int vrednost = Random.Range(0, pitanja.Count);
        izabranoPitanje = pitanja[vrednost];
        kvizUI.PostaviPitanje(izabranoPitanje);
        pitanja.RemoveAt(vrednost);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (statusIgre == StatusIgre.IgraSe)
        {
            trenutnoVreme -= Time.deltaTime;
            PodesiVreme(trenutnoVreme);
        }
    }

    private void PodesiVreme(float vrednost)
    {
        TimeSpan vreme = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(vrednost);

        kvizUI.VremeTekst.text = "Vreme:" + vreme.ToString("mm':'ss");

        if (trenutnoVreme <= 0)
        {
            statusIgre = StatusIgre.Sledece;
            kvizUI.KrajIgre.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public bool Odgovor(string odgovoreno)
    {
        bool tacanOdgovor = false;

        if (odgovoreno == izabranoPitanje.tacanOdgovor)
        {
            tacanOdgovor = true;
            brojacBodova += 50;
            kvizUI.BodoviTekst.text = "Bodovi:" + brojacBodova;
            

        }
        else
        {
            ostatakZivota--;
            kvizUI.OduzmiZivot(ostatakZivota);

            if (ostatakZivota <= 0)
            {
                
                statusIgre = StatusIgre.Sledece;
                kvizUI.KrajIgre.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        if (statusIgre == StatusIgre.IgraSe)
        {
            if (pitanja.Count > 0)
            {
                Invoke("IzaberiPitanje", 0.4f);
            }
            else
            {
                statusIgre = StatusIgre.Sledece;
                kvizUI.KrajIgre.SetActive(true);
            }

        }


        return tacanOdgovor;
    }

}

[System.Serializable]
public class Pitanje
{
    public string informacijaPitanja;
    public List<string> opcije;
    public string tacanOdgovor;
    public TipPitanja tipPitanja;
    public Sprite pitanjeSaSlikom;
    public AudioClip pitanjeSaZvukom;
    public UnityEngine.Video.VideoClip pitanjeSaVideom;
    public int brojPokusaja = 3;
    

    




    public bool JeTacanOdgovor(string odgovor)
    {
        return odgovor == tacanOdgovor;
    }
}






        [System.Serializable]
public enum TipPitanja
{
    TEKST,
    SLIKA,
    VIDEO,
    ZVUK
}

[System.Serializable]
public enum StatusIgre
{
    Sledece,
    IgraSe
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

I expect that someone will be able to help me with this, because this is my graduation project, I have done everything and prepared, but the only thing stopping me is this addition that I am missing, when I manage to add those 3 attempts on every question, my project can be completed.

Comment: Huge general suggestion - even more if asking for help online: Code in **English**! It is **the** commonly used language in programming and world-wide main communitcation language anyway ...  and helps us to understand what your code is supposed to be and do without needing to parse it line by line / translate it first

Comment: Without going through all your code - mainly because see above comment - In `KvizUI.PostaviPitanje` I see you are setting `trenutniPokusaj = 0;` and I don't see it being touched anywhere else ... => your `switch(trenutniPokusaj)` will **never** do anything it all .. you probably rather wanted to do `trenutniPokusaj ++;` to increase the counter by one each time and handle the case according to that ... then every time you go to a **new question** reset it to `0`

Comment: I'm sorry, there are some things left in the code that I didn't delete after trying to create the code, the picture I sent you of the blue square with orange brackets (in Inspector in Unity), is my question content, it's the ScriptDataQuiz (SkriptaPodatakaKviza) script, the Question class (public class Pitanje) has been added to the OtherQuizManager (DrugiKvizMenadzer) script, and everything that is in it, that in Inspector, informacija pitanja is question text , opcije  are buttons that you use to select an answer,  it would be easier for me to record a video and send it

Comment: I can send you the code in English, I'm new here on stuck overflow, so I still don't know how to set something up

Comment: What questions do you have now?